# ORA-00913 in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-insert

I'm using Oracle SQL and I'm trying do run the following query:

```
    INSERT
INTO data_mapp_info
  (
    data_mapp_info_id,
    data_mapp_camp_id,
    data_mapp_info,
    data_mapp_info_regs,
    dt_first,
    dt_ult_modf,
    user_ult_modf
  )
  VALUES
  (
    (SELECT MAX(data_mapp_info_id)+1 AS data_mapp_info_id
      FROM MAPP.DATA_MAPP_INFO
    )
    ,
    77,
    'Value 1',
    (SELECT MAX(data_mapp_info_regs),
      CASE data_mapp_info_regs
        WHEN NULL
        THEN 1
        ELSE MAX(data_mapp_info_regs)+1
      END
    FROM MAPP_SOA.DATA_MAPP_info
    WHERE data_mapp_camp_id = 77
    ),
    sysdate,
    sysdate,
    'user.name'
  ) ;
```

For the value of **data_mapp_info_regs** I'm trying to set as **1** if it's **NULL** and get the previous max value plus one if it already exists for a setted index **data_mapp_camp_id**. But I get the error *ORA-00913: "too many values"*.

How do I fix this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, the 2nd subquery should be modified to this:

```
INSERT INTO data_mapp_info (data_mapp_info_id,
                            data_mapp_camp_id,
                            data_mapp_info,
                            data_mapp_info_regs,
                            dt_first,
                            dt_ult_modf,
                            user_ult_modf)
        VALUES (
                  (SELECT MAX (data_mapp_info_id) + 1 AS data_mapp_info_id
                     FROM MAPP.DATA_MAPP_INFO),
                  77,
                  'Value 1',
                  -- This subquery should be modified
                  (SELECT NVL (MAX (data_mapp_info_regs), 0) + 1
                     FROM MAPP_SOA.DATA_MAPP_info
                    WHERE data_mapp_camp_id = 77),
                  --
                  SYSDATE,
                  SYSDATE,
                  'user.name');
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very very much. I didn't know yet this NVL function. Thank you again! =^^=

Answer (score 1):

This part of the query is returning two values, you can only return one value as it corresponds to a single column in the table you are inserting in to:

```
(SELECT MAX(data_mapp_info_regs),
      CASE data_mapp_info_regs
        WHEN NULL
        THEN 1
        ELSE MAX(data_mapp_info_regs)+1
      END
    FROM MAPP_SOA.DATA_MAPP_info
    WHERE data_mapp_camp_id = 77
    ),
```

Comment: I don't know SQL very well, I wrote this query based on existing ones. Could you help me to fix it, please, so this part can return only one value? :)